# Dynamically appending a div tag in jQuery mobile page

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a jQuery mobile sample application in which I am retrieving values in a grid (dynamically) according to the search location being entered.

The code is as follows:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
         {
    $('#stoplist').hide();
    $('#searchstop').change(function() {
    var searchstop=$('#searchstop').val();


$.ajax({  

    type: "GET",
    url: "BilaagValues?searchstop="+searchstop,  
    success:function (check) {
        console.log(check);
            var output = JSON.parse(check);
            console.log(output);

            $("#stoplist").show();
            $("#stop1").html(output.stopName);
            $("#mailbox1").html(output.mailboxno);
            $("#mailboxname").html(output.mailName);
            $("#advtbox1").html(output.advtno);
            $("#advtboxname").html(output.advtname);
    },

    success:function (check1) {
        console.log(check1);
            var output = JSON.parse(check1);
            console.log(output);

            $("#stoplist1").show();
            $("#stop2").append(output.stopName);
            $("#mailbox2").append(output.mailboxno);
            $("#mailboxname1").append(output.mailName);
            $("#advtbox2").append(output.advtno);
            $("#advtboxname1").append(output.advtname);

    }
    });
    });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="header" id="header">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" id="header"></a>
    <h1>Ruteoversikt</h1>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="header">Rediger</a>
</div>
 <div>  
 <input id="searchstop"  placeholder = "Stop pa Navvn" /></div>
<hr>
   <div id="unitno">221721_0030</div>
<hr>
<br/>
<hr>
<div id="stoplist">
<div class="ui-grid-b" id="address1">
<img id="picture1" src="post1.jpg"/>

<div id="stop1"></div><br>

<div id="mailbox1" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: double; border-color: grey; background-color:green"></div>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  <div id="mailboxname"></div> 
<div id="advtbox1" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: double; border-color: grey; "></div> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  <div id="advtboxname"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="stoplist1">
<div class="ui-grid-b" id="address1">


<div id="stop2"></div><br>

<div id="mailbox2" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: double; border-color: grey; background-color:green"></div>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  
<div id="mailboxname1"></div> 
<div id="advtbox2" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: double; border-color: grey; "></div> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  <div id="advtboxname1"></div>

</div>
</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>

    Now here the problem which is arising is that I want the 2nd set of values ie. in div with id "stopList1" to be appended below the first set of values which are there in first grid. In simple terms, The values retrieved for 2nd search should be appended below the first set of values but what is happening in my case is that the next set of values are getting appended above the first set of values,,, in the same grid...!!!!
```

How to resolve this????

Kindly help with your suggestions.

Comment: why do you have 2 success handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the content with the new values added onto the original content.
`$('#stoplist1').html($('#stoplist1').html() + 'Whatever code you want here');`

Answer (score 0):

$('#stoplist1').append('Whatever code you want here');